# How do I hide the properties panel in the Graph Editor?

Tags: interface, graph-editor

How do I hide the properties panel in the Graph Editor?
Screenshot says it all. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle on / off with <kbd>N</kbd> or via View / Properties

Comment: ...or dragging the panel left border to the right